# Adding @click or router via filter

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I get the post content with REST api, stripped of all html tags.

```
{'post': {'Content': 'test content with #hashtag'}}
```

I create hashtags from the content with filter and regex.

```
<div v-html="$options.filters.customFilter(post.Content)"></div>
(...)
methods: 
   ale(tag) {
      alert('asdf')
   }
customFilter(val) {
      val = val.replace(/#(\S*)/g, '<a @click="ale(\'asdf\')" href="http://localhost:8080/tag/$1">$1</a>')
      return val
    }
```

The problems is that this filter will create html link and force whole web reload (and not the router way)

I tried doing @click but vue doesn't interpret it (is plain text `@click` in dom)

How can i trigger router or @click from filter?

If i can't is there other way to do this??

**EDIT**
The full code is

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <li v-bind:key="index" v-for="(post, index) in posts">
      <div v-html="$options.filters.customFilter(post.Content)"></div>
    </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Posta',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App POST',
      posts: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ale() {
      alert('asdf')
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.posts = [{Content: 'test with #hashtag'}]
  },
  filters: {
    customFilter(val) {
      // ...
      val = val.replace(/#(\S*)/g, '<a @click="ale(\'asdf\')" href="http://localhost:8080/tag/$1">$1</a>')
      return val
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Could you show the full code where you did the filter?

Comment: @JohnKennedy i added full code, can you look at it?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using plain `<a>` tag
you must use `<router-link :to="dynamicValue">`

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts" v-bind:key="index">
      <router-link :to="getDynamicUrl(post.Content)">{{post.something}}</router-link>
    </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Posta',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App POST',
      posts: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ale() {
      alert('asdf')
    },
    getDynamicUrl(val) {
       return val; //somethingWith val
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.posts = [{Content: 'test with #hashtag'}]
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@click.prevent` to prevent the default action of a hard load of the page: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Then use Vue Router `push` or some other programmatic navigation to change vue routes: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Its totally unrelated to question.

Comment: See Georgi's answer